# RoR - en.yml file validation message for nested object/association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, associations, yaml

Having issues with validation messages in en.yml for associations.

This is the message I'm seeing: 
    **Name infos prev first name can't be blank**

2 things I'd like to change:
1.  "Name infos" is the name of the associated model and I don't want it to appear 
2. "prev first name" should instead say "Previous First Name"

I've been googling, searching and trying different things.  From what I've seen, the below "should" work but it's not (I've even restarted the app).

```
**contact_info.rb:** 
class ContactInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :name_infos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :name_infos, :allow_destroy => true
end


**name_info.rb:**
class NameInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact_info

      validates :prev_first_name, :presence => true, 
                   :if => :name_subcat_is_first_name?

      private

      def name_subcat_is_first_name?
        subcat == 'first'
      end

end

**routes.rb:**    
    resources :users do
       resources :contact_infos do
         collection do
           get 'get_full_fields'
           get 'clear_fields'
         end
       resources :name_infos
    end
  end

**en.yml:**    
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      contact_info:
        name_infos:
          prev_first_name: "Previous First Name"
```

Whenever I test this in the console, it doesn't change:

```
irb(main):050:0> ContactInfo.human_attribute_name("prev_first_name")
=> "Prev first name"
irb(main):051:0> NameInfo.human_attribute_name("prev_first_name")
=> "Prev first name"
```

I've tried:

```
**en.yml:**

en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      users:
         contact_info:
           name_infos:
             prev_first_name: "Previous First Name"
```

but it doesn't make a difference.

Can anyone shed light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the format is like this (since `prev_first_name` is an attribute of the NameInfo model):

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      name_info:
        prev_first_name: "Previous First Name"
```

Note that the model name (`name_info`) is singular, not plural.